# Difference between MariaDB-server and mariadb-server

Tags: linux, mariadb

I want to install mariadb database but i don't know the difference between these two packages.

MariaDB-server.x86_64 : MariaDB database server binaries

mariadb-server.x86_64 : The MariaDB server and related files

please tell me about the difference.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

As I know, there is no difference between these two distributions in practice except that the `MariaDB-server.x86_64` package is developed and maintained by the MariaDB community and provided by its official repository while the `mariadb-server.x86_64` package is offered by a CentOS repository.

Both packages should contain the MariaDB database server binary files and the additional required components. Maybe you see a few difference in configuration files and components which are not important. Installing the official MariaDB package is recommended.